# How to track changes to a list

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, dictionary, vector

I have an immutable base list of items that I want to perform a number of operations on: edit, add, delete, read. The actual operations will be queued up and performed elsewhere (sent up to the server and a new list will be sent down), but I want a representation of what the list would look like with the current set of operations applied to the base list.

My current implementation keeps a vector of ranges and where they map to. So an unedited list has one range from 0 to length that maps directly to the base list. If an add is performed in index 5, then we have 3 ranges: 0-4 maps to base list 0-4. 5 maps to the new item, and 6-(length+1) maps to 5-length. This works, however with a lot of adds and deletes, reads degrades to O(n).

I've thought of using hashmaps but the shifts in ranges that can occur with inserts and deletes presents a challenge. Is there some way to achieve this so that reads are around O(1) still?

Comment: How do you intend to perform add if the original list is immutable?

Comment: You are not going to be able to avoid a degradation in performance as you add operations needed to calculate the *virtual* resultant list. I am interested in solutions to make this as efficient as possible though because I have a similar *non-destructive editing* problem.

Comment: The changes will be applied on the server and we will get an update version later.

Comment: So why not just store a list of indices instead of ranges?

Comment: That's a possibility that I've considered, however that requires a full O(n) memory space every time. Which can be costly if the list is filled with tens of thousands of items and is update every frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a roughly balanced tree of ranges, where each node kept a record of the total number of elements below it in the tree, you could answer reads in worst case time the depth of the tree, which should be about log(n). Perhaps a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap would be one of the easier balanced trees to implement for this.

If you had a lot of repetitious reads and few modifications, you might gain by keeping a hashmap of the results of reads since the last modification, clearing it on modification.